# Как реализовать циферблат, где отображается быстрая смена цифр, между нулевым значением и финальным?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Сначала у нас ряд нулей, затем на месте нулей происходит мелькание других цифр, после чего все позиции занимаются определёнными цифрами.
 Каким образом можно реализовать подобное, посредством `CSS`, `jQuery`, ... ?
 У меня 8 таких ячеек, в каждой будет своё число. Думал написать код замены значений (ряд замен для реализации мелькающих значений, после чего - финальная замена), но что-то не видел такого механизма в пособии по `jQuery`. Может его и нет ?
В общем, мне нужна, прежде всего, концепция. Если есть решение - вообще супер.

Comment: Скорее всего нужно писать код на JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function runTest(){
  var counter = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    $(".display").css("color", "red").text(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    counter++;
    if (counter > 40) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      $(".display").css("color", "green").text(999);
    }
  }, 30);
}
```

```css
.display{
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  font-size:25px;
  width:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="display">&nbsp;</div>

<br/>
<button onclick="runTest()">Run</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, отличное решение :)